# No available Hazelcast instance"HazelcastCachingProvider.HAZELCAST_CONFIG_LOCATION"

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, hazelcast

any idea about this error:

No available Hazelcast instance. Please specify your Hazelcast configuration file path via "HazelcastCachingProvider.HAZELCAST_CONFIG_LOCATION"

Working fine with this cfg in a local kubernetes, but always getting this error when i set Kubernetes = true and multicast to false. I'm trying to use it for Liberty in IBMCloud Kubernetes.

```
    <hazelcast xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config
       https://hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.12.xsd">
    <group>
        <name>cluster</name>
    </group>
    <network>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="true"/>
            <kubernetes enabled="false"/>
        </join>
    </network>
</hazelcast>
```

server.xml

```
<httpSessionCache libraryRef="jCacheVendorLib" 
     uri="file:${server.config.dir}hazelcast-config.xml" />
 <library id="jCacheVendorLib">
     <file name="${shared.config.dir}/lib/global/hazelcast-3.12.6.jar" />
 </library>
```

This is what I done:

I have a docker image using liberty, in the liberty configuration I set the following configuration to use hazelcast:

```
    <server>
    <featureManager>
        ...
        <feature>sessionCache-1.0</feature>
        ...
    </featureManager>
...

    <httpSessionCache libraryRef="jCacheVendorLib" 
        uri="file:${server.config.dir}hazelcast-config.xml" />
    <library id="jCacheVendorLib">
        <file name="${shared.config.dir}/lib/global/hazelcast-3.12.6.jar" />
    </library>
...
</server>
```

Then I set the configuration in hazelcast-config.xml. I only get the error when I set kubernetes=true and multicast=false. If I left kubernetes = false and multicast = true works fine on my local kubernetes, but hazelcast can't find other pods when I deployed it on cloud (looks like ips are on a different network)

```
    <hazelcast xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config
       https://hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.12.xsd">
    <group>
        <name>cluster</name>
    </group>
    <network>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="true"/>
            <kubernetes enabled="false"/>
        </join>
    </network>
</hazelcast>
```

Also I ran the RBAC yaml.

And run the following yaml to deploy it:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: employee-service
  labels:
    app: employee-service
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: employee-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: employee-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: myapp
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: multicast
              containerPort: 5701

------------------------------
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: employee-service
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9080
    targetPort: 9080
    nodePort: 31234
```

Comment: Did you follow documentation steps - [How to Use Embedded Hazelcast on Kubernetes](https://hazelcast.com/blog/how-to-use-embedded-hazelcast-on-kubernetes/) ? When this issue occurs? Could you provide your steps and your environment details?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Hazelcast Kubernetes plugin for the discovery, please make sure that you [configured RBAC](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes#granting-permissions-to-use-kubernetes-api), for example with the following command.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/master/rbac.yaml
```

Please also make sure that the [default parameters](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes#hazelcast-configuration) work for you (you run your Hazelcast in the same namespace, etc.).

If that does not help, please share the full StackTrace logs.